# Write before and after decorator

Tags: python, decorator

I have following sample code,

```
def say_hello(f):
    def wrap():
        print "Hello"
    return wrap

def say_bye(f):
    def wrap():
        print "Bye"
    return wrap

@say_hello
@say_bye
def process():
    return "Processing"

process()
```

Output:

```
Hello
```

I was expecting output as:

```
Bye
Hello
Processing
```

1. What could be wrong?
2. How to make decorators those will be called before and after function call?

Means, with above example, Can I have output:

```
    Hello
    Processing
    Bye
```

Comment: `f()` needs to be called inside of your `wrap` functions.  `processing` should print in addition to returning a value otherwise you won't see it in the order it was called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "wrap" functions returned from your decorators don't actually call the function they were supposed to be wrapping. This is a problem, because the function returned from a decorator isn't called before the wrapped function is called; it *replaces* the function it's wrapping. The following decorator syntax:

```
@some_decorator
def func(arg):
    function_body()
```

is syntactical sugar for the following code:

```
def func(arg):
    function_body()
func = some_decorator(func)
```

Thus, what you want is

```
def say_hello(f):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        print "Hello"
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrap

def say_bye(f):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        return_value = f(*args, **kwargs)
        print "Bye"
        return return_value
    return wrap

@say_hello
@say_bye
def process():
    return "Processing"
```

This will produce

```
Hello
Processing
Bye
```

Answer (score 3):

You should call the function `f()` inside the decorators. Now to print the value in 2nd decorator, after your after your function executes, you can just make the function call in that decorator (`say_bye`) before printing `"Bye"`:

```
def say_hello(f):
    def wrap():
        print "Hello"
        f()          # call after printing
    return wrap

def say_bye(f):
    def wrap():
        f()          # call before printing
        print "Bye"
    return wrap

@say_hello
@say_bye
def process():
    print "Processing"

process()
```

**Output:**

```
Hello
Processing
Bye
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works the same as the following code:

```
fun = say_hello(say_bye(process))
fun()
```

where say_hello() doesn't use it's parameter at all.